# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE from Google Storage / Google App Engine?

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I need to run a process that will perform about 10,000 mysql inserts into a GoogleSQL instance. Normally, I would use a `load data local infile` query for this to avoid the script timing out, but my app is running in Google App Engine which has a read-only filesystem. Normally, when I need my GAE app to write to the filesystem, I can just use file names prefixed with `gs://` and the php code will read/write to/from Google Storage transparently.

However, I doubt that MySQL will understand a file path of `gs://path/to/my/file`.

Is there another way that I can make a dynamically generated local file available in a Google App Engine environment so that I can load it into my GoogleSQL instance?

Otherwise, I feel like I'm going to need to build a looping ajax system to insert X rows at a time until it's gone through however many I need (10,000... 20,000, etc).

I know that I can put multiple `values` sets into a single insert to speed it all up and I'm planning to do that, but with the datasets as large as I'm dealing with, that still won't speed things up enough to avoid the timeouts consistently.

Comment: By GoogleSQL/MySQL are you referring to Google Cloud SQL? If so, can't you use its importing data recipes which explicitly support GCS: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to Google Cloud SQL. Those instructions are only for doing imports via the web console and I'm trying to find a programmatic way to accomplish the import.